# How to grant rights to HTTP namespace on installed service?

Tags: c#, wcf, http, deployment, windows-services

I have written a Windows Service, that opens up a WCF service on port 8003 of the local machine.  Or at least, it's *supposed* to.  The service can't start up, because of the famous exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.AddressAccessDeniedException: HTTP could not register URL http://+:8003/TRConfigurationService/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details).
```

This problem is addressed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amitlale/archive/2007/01/29/addressaccessdeniedexception-cause-and-solution.aspx), with a very simple answer: run a command prompt in admin mode, and execute:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8003/ user=DOMAIN\UserName
```

All very well and good, and I can do that manually on my local dev machine.  But how do I do that on the client installation, without the user having to do anything other than click "Yes" (only once after/during installation) when prompted to run in Admin mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer is simply to make sure the service runs in admin mode, then there's no problem!  For those who don't know, add an app.manifest file to the project, and set

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: According to PaulWH, running your WCF service under elevated privileges is a golden example of what not to do (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paulwh/archive/2007/05/04/addressaccessdeniedexception-http-could-not-register-url-http-8080.aspx).

Comment: I think the context of how this will be used makes this  a good or bad answer.  I am trying to simply spin up a local servicehost for use in a unit test.  This solution is the simplest and most reusable.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you should be able to [do it using WIX](http://damianblog.com/2008/02/21/configuring-http-namespace-reservations-on-vista-using-wix/).

Comment: Far superior to, and less risky than, Shaul's suggestion. I'd give you +2 if I could *grin*